# How do I use $wpdb?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to add a voting system to my website which uses the CMS WordPress.

I suppose AJAX should be used and I have a template file and an external PHP file which accesses the database, but that obviously doesn't work well.

I get this error:

> "Call to undefined function add_action()".

`$wpdb` probably can't be used in an external PHP file.

How can I define `$wpdb` to be able to use it?

Comment: Why not use Wordpress's own [AJAX System](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) by adding your action to functions.php?

Comment: See the Codex on wpdb (just Google it) and check out @Otome's comment, then post back with specific issues. Including external files doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: In essence, I want to execute a mysql query when users clicks (a specific object) without having to reload the page.

Comment: As @Otome said, you should use the WordPress built-in Ajax API. Otherwise, you have to load the WordPress environment this way : `require( 'path/to/wordpress/wp-load.php' );`

Comment: Sorry, noob here... How do I do that? In that case I don't need an external PHP file?

Comment: When I insert this code at the beginning, it works. 

`$file = dirname(__FILE__);
$file = substr($file, 0, stripos($file, "wp-content") );
require( $file . "/wp-load.php");`

Is this way to go?

Comment: You have to read [http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins)...

Answer (score 0):

You should use the $wpdb as global variable and you can call it from anywhere in the function.